# Facing problems in multiple table joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

There are 4 tables.

- items ( item_id, item_name, item_owner)
- groups ( grp_id, grp_name, grp_owner)
- users (grp_id, usr_ref)
- share (item_id, grp_id)

My objective is to get a list of all those items where item_owner = user_id ( say 123 ) or user_id belongs to a group with which the item is shared.

A basic query implementation to retrieve all items shared with a group to which a particular user_id belongs would be

```
select i.item_id from items i
left outer join share on share.item_id = i.item_id
left outer join users on users.grp_id = share.grp_id
left outer join groups on groups.grp_id = share.grp_id
where users.usr_ref = user_id
```

And to include all other elements of which user_id is the owner, i did something like

```
select * from items where owner = user_id or item_id in ( 
select i.item_id from items i
left outer join share on share.item_id = i.item_id
left outer join users on users.grp_id = share.grp_id
left outer join groups on groups.grp_id = share.grp_id
where users.usr_ref = user_id )
```

which i suppose is a very bad implementation as the item_id needs to be searched everytime in the array obtained from the joins. How can i improve my sql statement.

Also is there any other way in which i can redesign my table structure so that i can implement the query in some other way ?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need `INNER JOIN` in this case because you need to get an item that has connection on all tables. Your current query uses `LEFT JOIN` that is why even an item that has not associated on any user will be shown on the list. Give this a try,

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*
FROM    items a
        INNER JOIN `share` b
            ON a.item_ID = b.item_ID
        INNER JOIN groups c
            ON b.grp_ID = c.grp_ID
        INNER JOIN users d
            ON c.grp_ID = d.grp_ID
WHERE   d.usr_ref = user_ID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

```
select i.item_id from items i
inner join share on share.item_id = i.item_id
inner join users on users.grp_id = share.grp_id
inner join groups on groups.grp_id = share.grp_id
where (users.usr_ref = @user_id or @user_id is null) and  (i.item_id = @item_id or @item_id is null)
```

I'm guessing that you will always pass one paramether or the other one, not both, so the other one (the non-passed) will be null

also, why are you using left join? use inner instead, because you don't want null fields

Comment: there is no `INNEROUTER` join.

Comment: sorry, was a typo replacing left outer join

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm not understanding your question, but can you not just use `OR` with your first query:

```
select i.item_id from items i
   left outer join share on share.item_id = i.item_id
   left outer join users on users.grp_id = share.grp_id
   left outer join groups on groups.grp_id = share.grp_id
where i.item_owner = @user_id or users.usr_ref = @user_id
```